Material Preview Bugged
After updating to 4.2, materials in material preview do not display properly unless scene lights in the view port shading tab is activated.



Hello and welcome. Do you have a question we can answer? This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see Where to Report a Bug. If the issue is in or caused by a third party addon, please report it to the addon author instead.

Hello yes it looks like a bug, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Try to re-set HDRI again

I have even gone to the extent of resetting everything to factory settings more than once @Crantisz

it works fine for me in Blender 4.2
